# How compute the exchange rate in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, validation

I have a query that uses PO_PurchaseOrder_Line table. I need to get the exchange rate because the PurchaseCost table is in Taiwan Dollar currency.

[image]

Comment: nothing visible in pic

Comment: exchange rate?  1 USD = 32 Taiwan Dollar.

Comment: You'd need a table giving you exchange rates for each date or date range. Then you'd join this table in order to access the rate valid on an order date. The rest is multiplication or division, depending on how the rate is stored: `UnitPrice * ConversionRate` or `UnitPrice / ConversionRate`.

Comment: Which currency do you want to convert to?  You don't say, but it will be crucial.  Different companies use different rules for different currencies and different time periods and it depends on whether you're hedging your conversion rates and … generally, there is no single answer, as Thorsten Kettner said.  Once you've decided on a conversion rate between the currencies you're interested in, it is fairly straight-forward, but deciding which conversion rate to use is anything but straight-forward.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
declare @totalAmountUSD bigint
declare @exchangeRate int
Set @exchangeRate =0.031
Set @totalAmountUSD=@totalValue* @exchangeRate;
```

I have used the following link to find the exchange rate

https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=PJ1jV9jzM-nI8Afz573wDw#q=COnvert+taiwan+dollar+to+usd

I would also recommend you to create a table for exchange rate.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/553206/An-Introduction-to-Real-Time-Stock-Market-Data-Pro

http://jsonrates.com/

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forex-exchange-exchange-rates

Use the data coming from their API. Insert them in the Currency Table. Now use this Currency Table as your exchange rate table